# How to create the general formula for minimum volume after using Lagrange's multipliers?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, operations-research

Context:
So I was working on finding the relationship between the variables in an isosceles triangular prism a,b(side lengths of rectangle and h (height of triangle). The problem is that I'm trying to find a general relationship between a,b,h so that I can use them to optimize the packaging of any isosceles triangular prism, for which I know the variables a,b,h, but I'm not sure how to continue. I'm using the bottom part of this thesis as a refference: https://www.clastify.com/ia/maths/5fba8e3bf4fda55746067a1b
My working looks as follows:

[image]

I partially differentiated both equations then and used LaGrange's multipliers to set them equal to the constant lambda:
[image]

Next I set Eq. 1. a) and 3. a) equal to each other doing the same with 2. a) and 3.a) [wrongly annotated as 1. b) and 2. a)]

[image]

I then used symbolab to rewrite the Eq. in terms of b so that I can substitute the re-arranged Volume formula
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what is the optimization problem. I assume you are trying to find maximum volume, keeping the surface area constant. It's always good to explicitly write your goal and constraints. If so, your reuslt is quite intuitive. You found equilateral triangle.

Comment: My goal was to find the relation between h,b and a such that Volume is maximum and area is minimum (hence the partial differentiation) for an isosceles triangle prism (see figure at the top). I have found two equations in terms of V but dont know how to go further anymore.